# How to write this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, minimum

Suppose I have a table that has three integer fields and one string field (just data).

For example it looks like:

```
Id      Category    Value   Data
1       1           3       ...
2       1           4       ...
3       2           2       ...
4       2           4       ...
5       3           5       ...
6       3           6       ...
7       3           2       ...
8       4           1       ...
```

What I want to do is for each `Category`, include the row with the minimum `Value` field in the result set. In this case, it would return:

```
Id      Category    Value   Data
1       1           3       ...
3       2           2       ...
7       3           2       ...
8       4           1       ...
```

How to write such a query?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using the `GROUP BY` clause and `MIN` clause?

Comment: He's also asking for the IDs, though, which GROUP BY and MIN wouldn't return. javic how do you want to resolve ties e.g. if there were two rows with category 1 value 3? Show them both? Show just one of them? Which?

Comment: Oh, you can assume that there will not be tie cases. There won't be two rows with the same category AND value. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select T1.Id,
       T1.Category,
       T1.Value,
       T1.Data
from YourTable as T1
  inner join (
               select Category,
                      min(Value) as Value
               from YourTable
               group by Category
             ) as T2
    on T1.Category = T2.Category and
       T1.Value = T2.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from mytable t
join (select category, min(value) as value from mytable group by 1) x
    on t.value = x.value and t.category = x.category
```

The inner select gets the categories and values needed for the final result, then you join back to the main table to get *all* the columns.

Comment: Ok thanks! That looks perfect. Not sure about performance but I'm not hungry for performance on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT category, MIN(value) as Value
FROM table
GROUP BY category
```

Use the `MIN` function and `GROUP BY` the results on the Category column.

Comment: Yeah.. I need to get not only the min values but also the row. Thanks for trying though :)